# Stretch Javascript Code to fill the web page

Tags: html, javascript

So, I recently am working on a game in RPGMaker MV. The thing is that I set up a website for testing with the game loaded on it. The thing is that the game on the website always runs in the resolution I gave it using a plugin (1366x768). However, no scaling is performed. What I want to do is make it so the game stretches to the browser window, ignoring the aspect ratio, so there are no borders.

Here's my HTML code (from RPG Maker MV. Based on research I think "pixi.js" is the engine's display script.):

{


    
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        Game
    
    
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
    

}

(Unfortunately I do not know how to place code in a code block on Mobile devices.)

Comment: This question belongs to stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Private Oops, I got confused with the website.